# Execute Windows commands from Java

Tags: java, command-prompt

I try to use following command to execute a Windows command in a given directory.

```
try{
    String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

    out.write("cd /d C:\\_private\\Files\\testfiles".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.write("for /f \"DELIMS=\" %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move \"%x*.*\" \"%x\\\"".getBytes());
    out.close();
}catch(IOException e){
}
```

It just open up a Command prompt in directory, where Java project is located.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Programming: call an exe from Java and passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434009/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-cmd-with-long-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434009/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-cmd-with-long-parameters)

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 3):

That process is already terminated. You only start `cmd` to start another `cmd`. That first `cmd`, to which you have a variable and to which you're writing is gone. Only the second one remains open.

Instead, start CMD only once and tell it to remain open:

```
String command = "cmd /k";
```

Next, please have a look on how  to start programs with arguments.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/k").start();
```

Comment: I tried this way too, but file is not created: `String[] cmd = {"\"cmd.exe\", \"/k\"", "cd /d C:\\_private\\Files\\myfiles", "copy NUL EMptyFile.txt"}; Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();`

Comment: @plaidshirt That's not the right way. Just start `cmd /k` and do the rest (i.e. `cd` and `copy`) via `OutputStream out`